# MPI Gather different Size

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a cluster of 10 computers and 2 variables in c++
 - result : size int 100;
 - result_final : (only on host) size int 1000;
how can I gather the pieces of 'result' and create 'result_final' as their size differs.
Thank you!

```
int *rcounts = (int *) malloc(commSize * sizeof(int));
int *displs = (int *) malloc(commSize * sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < commSize; ++i) {
    displs[i] = commRank * result_size * size;
    rcounts[i] = result_size * size;
}
MPI_Gatherv(h_result, result_size * size, MPI_INT, h_result_final, rcounts,
        displs, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: If you show us the code you have written people here will help.  If you don't people here will add useless comments (such as this one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the size of each piece differs you would use `MPI_Gatherv()` instead of `MPI_Gather()`. The same is also true for `MPI_Scatter()` vs `MPI_Scatterv()`.

Comment: so i could do it like this?
MPI_Gatherv(h_result, result_size * size, MPI_INT, h_result_final, displs, rcounts, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
?

Comment: Did you have a look at the description of `MPI_Gatherv`? If you are gathering equally sized pieces then use `MPI_Gather`. Please, have a look at the documentation - it is very useful!

Comment: why? thats my code...
 int *rcounts = (int *) malloc(commSize * sizeof(int));
 int *displs = (int *) malloc(commSize * sizeof(int));
 for (i = 0; i < commSize; ++i) {
  displs[i] = commRank * result_size * size;
  rcounts[i] = result_size * size;
 }
 MPI_Gatherv(h_result, result_size * size, MPI_INT, h_result_final, rcounts,
   displs, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

Comment: Since your counts are all the same, you'd better use `MPI_Gather`. That was not apparent from your initial question.

Comment: It should be: `MPI_Gatherv(h_result, result_size * size, MPI_INT, h_result_final, result_size * size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`. You deleted your previous code sample from the question so I am unsure if you should multiply both size arguments by `size`. Mind that sizes in both `MPI_Gather` and `MPI_Gatherv` are specified in elements and not in bytes.